# Create pdf in servlet using form data (iText)

Tags: jsp, servlets, pdf, itext

I'm not sure if this question has been asked I've searched all over the net for about a week now and found nothing yet. I basically want to be able to create a pdf using fields from a form, now I wrote a similar servlet a while back where I used form data to write an email and I tried using similar principles but it didn't work. I'm not sure if I've missed a trick or completely misunderstood something but this is the code I wrote.

```
<%@
page import="java.io.*, com.itextpdf.text.*, com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*"
%>
<%
    Document document=new Document(); 
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("C:\\hello.pdf"));
    document.open();
    document.add(new Paragraph("Daily Briefing Sheet"));
    document.add(new Paragraph(%><%request.getParameter("employeeid")%><%));
    document.close();
%>
```

I can create the pdf but as soon as i use this line it won't create it.

```
document.add(new Paragraph(%><%request.getParameter("employeeid")%><%));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made the rookie mistake of using another file that couldnt actually see the variables I was requesting because the button was going to a link not the form action destination

Answer (score 1):

why use JSP tags within scriptlets? just remove the SCRIPTLETS and it should work

```
<%@
page import="java.io.*, com.itextpdf.text.*, com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*"
%>
<%
    Document document=new Document(); 
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("C:\\hello.pdf"));
    document.open();
    document.add(new Paragraph("Daily Briefing Sheet"));
    document.add(new Paragraph(request.getParameter("employeeid")));
    document.close();
%>
```

Comment: I'll give it a go thanks, it worked for my email servlet. I may have found out why it was happening anyway think it may just be an issue with the way I've designed the HTML form that it doesn't know what the variable is.

Rookie mistake